# WordPress sidebar - Show all widget titles then all widget contents

Tags: wordpress, tabs, widget, sidebar

I'm building a wordpress plugin that turns widgets in a sidebar in to a tabbed-content area.

The sidebar contents currently output as: 
widget_title, widget-contents - widget_title, widget-contents

I would like them to output as: 
widget_title, widget_title - widget_contents, widget_contents

Here is my sidebar:

```
register_sidebar( array(
  'name' => __( 'Tabbed Sidebar', 'twentyeleven' ),
  'id' => 'tabbed-sidebar',
  'description' => __( '', 'twentyeleven' ),
  'before_widget' => '<div class="tab-widget">',
  'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
  'before_title' => '<h5 class="tab-title">',
  'after_title' => '</h5><div class="tab-content">',
) );
```

With the titles listing without being punctuated by the contents (and vice versa) the interface-design could have much more flexibility.

*edit*
I think I have it:

```
<div class="tabbed-headers"><?php foreach $widget echo $title titlecount++; ?></div>
<div class="tabbed-contents"><?php foreach $widget echo $content contentcount++; ?></div>
```

Any suggestions as to how I could do that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the begining, in the code:

```
<div class="tabbed-headers"><?php foreach $widget echo $title titlecount++; ?></div>
<div class="tabbed-contents"><?php foreach $widget echo $content contentcount++; ?></div>
```

you have a basic php mistake. you dont have a `;` after `$title` and `#content`.
so this code should be like:

```
<div class="tabbed-headers"><?php foreach $widget echo $title; titlecount++; ?></div>
<div class="tabbed-contents"><?php foreach $widget echo $content; contentcount++; ?></div>
```

but unless `$widget`, `$title` and `$content` are veriables you made, it won't work by wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I got the plugin working here: https://github.com/dabzo/totally-tabular